# Projecting rectangular stereography centred on 42°N, 10°E

Tags: meteorology, precipitation, weather-satellites, projection, coordinate-system

I am reposting from GIS Stack Exchange as here might also be someone who might help:

I have a precipitation GRIB2 file obtained at EUMETSAT H-SAF I am able to decode it to ascii but the software I am using (gdal, ArcMap,...) does not recognize the projection (in the title) so I am not able to properly project to Web Mercator for example. 
So can anyone please suggest software that preferably works on Ubuntu and projects either grib2 files to other projections or is able to recognise the projection from decoded ascii.

Comment: I believe GrADS was solid at changing projections and was centered around grib2.  But it's been so long, not sure if it's exactly what you need.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I'll check, any suggestion is appreciated as I've been loosing my mind for 2 days now.

Comment: Seems to be the constant issue with GIS type stuff for me :-p :-p

Comment: This is just a stereographic projection clipped 
with a rectangular neatline: http://geophysics.eas.gatech.edu/classes/Intro_GMT/gmt_www/gmt/doc/html/GMT_Docs/node81.html Can your software do oblique azimuthal projections at all?

Comment: @Spencer yes it can. Thank you for your effort I found a solution and will post as answer

Comment: Although you found your solution: cdo (climate data operators) might help. With them, one could convert the grib into netcdf and interpolate it onto another grid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The product (H-SAF 05) manual stated the datasets are in the projection mentioned in the title. EUMETSAT user support answered me the datasets use a polar stereographic projection with 25-75°N lat, 25°W- 45°E long.